# how to make inside round in css

Tags: css

I want to make a `div` something like the below image in my website in css. I tried to round bottom borders with `border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;`, but it curves too much.

[image]

please help me to make it.

Comment: can you show a picture of the whole element ??

Comment: @Ahm. I whant a div like the below image, what elements to you want?

Comment: share us your html and css code. so that we can give better answer to your problem.

Comment: If 'border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;' is too much, can't you reduce the 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try stacking divs, set a container with `overflow: hidden` and then position 2 divs that are much bigger and have rounded border.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.inner, .outer{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 1000px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  left: -50%;
  /* only for the inner - will be overwritten in the next section*/
  top: -900px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}

.outer{ 
  top: -750px;
  background-color: #3E9AD2;;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="outer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't answer "do all the work for me questions", they are suppose to make an effort of their own. Second, don't use extra inner `div` for stuff like that, use the pseudo elements instead.

Comment: Usually you also want to place content in those areas, and with pseudo elements your options are limited.

Comment: @ItayGal in witch div do I have to place content?

Comment: Change the background color of each div and see the place each div takes. IF you need to place your content over the blue background then use the `outer` div. You'll probably need to place the content align to the bottom, otherwise you won't see it.

Comment: For that _content_ you can use an element. Most likely, if there should be content it should follow the curve, and for that one would be better of with SVG.